# Can I derive the mp3-filepath from SMPlayer-portable?

Tags: mplayer

I wonder: when playing e.g. an mp3 file in SMPlayer-portable version, can I derive one way or another the path of that file currently being played in SMPlayer?

I am building some macro's that need this information.

That is: the complete path to the mp3-file, or just the path to the containing directory of the mp3-file.

I am trying to accomplish this by performing an “IniRead” from the SMPlayer.ini file, section [directories], key “latest_dir”. But this doesn't work in many cases.

I experimented a lot, but I don't understand exactly when this .ini-key is overwritten.

The key doesn't update when you load a new mp3-file in SMPlayer.

Comment: Question answered on the SMPlayer support forum: [link](http://forum.smplayer.info/posting.php?mode=reply&f=2&t=8236&sid=7a8390b01ae7cc9623051b3406fdcefc)